# RunWith SpringJUnit4ClassRunner gives error fail to load ApplicationContext with InitializingBean

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-test

I am using InitializingBean to initialise static properties in a modal class. This object I am auto wiring in a service

When I write a test case of service, I throws error: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Config class

```
public class AppConfig {
    private String prop1;

    protected void setProp1(String prop) {
        this.prop1 = prop;
    }

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }
}
```

PropertyIntilizer class

```
public class PropertyIntializer implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        appConfig.setProp1("PROP");
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println(appConfig.getProp1());
    }
}
```

TestClass

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void testService(){
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This gives an error : Failed to load ApplicationContext

But when I remove Autowired AppConfig, it works

Edit:
TestConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "base.package" })
public class TestConfig {

}
```

my main classes are in base.package.main and test classes in base.package.test

Comment: Please show us the source code for `TestConfig`. Otherwise we can't really assist you.

Comment: Added code for `TestConfig`

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace for the "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error you are encountering?

Comment: How/where is `AppConfig` configured as a bean?

Answer (score 0):

similar issue got resolved for me by adding JRE(thats comes with application server in my case websphere) in buid path

Comment: I am running on tomcat. Which JRE is that? Also main code works fine, I am having problems with running test.

Comment: You can download the JRE from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html
similar issue got resolved for me by adding JRE in the buildpath also added the below dependency to build.gradle

compile group: 'org.apache.openejb', name: 'javaee-api', version: '6.0-6'